# git flow init -d default suggestions are empty

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm using Git flow on Windows. When I'm initializing my repo via

```
git flow init -d
```

I get the following output

```
Which branch should be used for bringing forth production releases?
- develop
- master
 Branch name for production releases: [master]

Which branch should be used for integration of the "next release"?
  - develop
Branch name for "next release" development: [develop]

How to name your supporting branch prefixes?
Feature branches? []
Bugfix branches? []
Release branches? []
Hotfix branches? []
Support branches? []
Version tag prefix? []
```

As can be seen, the default prefixes are empty. Can anyone tell me in which config file these prefixes are set?

The problem is that I'm using a PowerShell script to clone multiple repos and init the repos via `git flow init -d`, so I need the default values.

Thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might either be a bug or a voluntary change: at the very least someone posted a [github issue](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/6442) about this.

In the meantime, you can use:

```
git flow init -d --feature feature/  --bugfix bugfix/ --release release/ --hotfix hotfix/ --support support/ -t ''
```

As pointed out by @creativeDev, if you already did 'git flow init' you can force reinitialization by adding -f before -d:

```
git flow init -f -d --feature feature/  --bugfix bugfix/ --release release/ --hotfix hotfix/ --support support/ -t ''
```

*update 2020-08-25*: [this issue](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/6452) is asking the author, nvie, to mark the repository (?) as deprecated and make git-flow point in homebrew to [git-flow-avh](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh) instead

Comment: if you already did 'git flow init' you can force reinitialization by adding -f before -d
`git flow init -f -d --feature feature/  --bugfix bugfix/ --release release/ --hotfix hotfix/ --support support/ -t ''`

Answer (score 3):

Working with VSCode and devcontainers, I came across the same issue.  The version in use is:

```
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace# git flow version
1.12.0 (AVH Edition)
```

**NOTE:** This doesn't actually work.  The first init is on an empty repo and results in the `.git/config` not containing the `[gitflow "prefix"]` section.  When the `git flow feature start ABC` is executed, it defaults to the global section to create the `feature/ABC` branch.  Doing a subsequent `git flow init --default -f` results in the same error being seen.

There is a bug reported with the Ubuntu 20.04 package: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git-flow/+bug/1860086

Replacing the installed gitflow/git-flow files from the apt git-flow:1.12.0 package, with the **1.12.3 release from GitHub fixes the issue**.

```
wget https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/archive/1.12.3.tar.gz
tar xzf 1.12.3.tar.gz 
cd gitflow-avh-1.12.3/
cp git* /usr/lib/git-core/
```

An alternative is to set the prefixes at the global level:

```
git config --global gitflow.prefix.feature 'feature/';
git config --global gitflow.prefix.bugfix 'bugfix/';
git config --global gitflow.prefix.release 'release/';
git config --global gitflow.prefix.hotfix 'hotfix/';
git config --global gitflow.prefix.support 'support/';
git config --global gitflow.prefix.versiontag '';
git config --global gitflow.branch.master master;
```

End to end example with before and after:

**NOTE:** The the global master branch config actually does nothing. Even with version 1.12.3.

```
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace# mkdir wrong
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace# cd wrong
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace/wrong# git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/wrong/.git/
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace/wrong# git flow init --defaults
Using default branch names.
No branches exist yet. Base branches must be created now.
Branch name for production releases: [master] 
Branch name for "next release" development: [develop] 

How to name your supporting branch prefixes?
Feature branches? [] 
Bugfix branches? [] 
Release branches? [] 
Hotfix branches? [] 
Support branches? [] 
Version tag prefix? [] 
Hooks and filters directory? [/workspace/wrong/.git/hooks] 
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace/wrong# cd ..
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace#     git config --global gitflow.prefix.feature 'feature/';
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace#     git config --global gitflow.prefix.bugfix 'bugfix/';
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace#     git config --global gitflow.prefix.release 'release/';
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace#     git config --global gitflow.prefix.hotfix 'hotfix/';
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace#     git config --global gitflow.prefix.support 'support/';
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace#     git config --global gitflow.prefix.versiontag '';
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace#     git config --global gitflow.branch.master master;
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace# mkdir working
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace# cd working
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace/working# git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/working/.git/
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace/working# git flow init --defaults
Using default branch names.
No branches exist yet. Base branches must be created now.
Branch name for production releases: [master] 
Branch name for "next release" development: [develop] 
Hooks and filters directory? [/workspace/working/.git/hooks] 
root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace/working# git flow feature start ABC
Switched to a new branch 'feature/ABC'

Summary of actions:
- A new branch 'feature/ABC' was created, based on 'develop'
- You are now on branch 'feature/ABC'

Now, start committing on your feature. When done, use:

     git flow feature finish ABC

root@abc64e31b32e:/workspace/working#
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work.  Updated with a note explaining why.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use command, to run Git Init uninterrupted and you will get defaults:

> git flow init -fd